# Is there a way to close a dynamically loaded library in Android?

Tags: android, linux, shared-libraries, dalvik

As a preamble for non-Android people (some Linux folk may know the answer with this info):

Every application in Android is run in an instance of the Dalvik Virtual Machine.  When starting an application, an entity called the ActivityManager writes to a pipe to inform another entity, the Zygote, that an app needs to be launched.  The Zygote is a blank-slate Dalvik VM instance with libraries pre-loaded, and upon being summoned via a pipe, it clones itself and the clone lowers its permission level to the Linux user associated with the app to be launched.  This saves time and memory when launching apps - consider the alternative of reloading all of the libraries and doing all setup each time.

My issue is that there is a particular library that is loaded in Zygote that I want to close in this particular process, as I want to use my own version of the library.  I have linked my native code against MY .so file, which is copied into a proper folder and loaded via a Java layer "System.load('xyz')" when the application starts, but when my code runs, it is calling the functions of the original system's library and not mine.  When I run "cat /proc/NNNN/maps", I can see that the old library is in memory as well as mine.

Is there a way to close that particular library in my application?  If not, is there a way to ensure that any/every call to functions in that library are passed to MY version instead of the old version?

Thanks!

Comment: "Close" as in unload a previously loaded shared library?  There doesn't appear to be a way.  See: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-ndk/59Xu4kKjgnA and https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-ndk/sf56xVIySfI

Comment: @MarsAtomic: Those posts are about unloading libraries that the app itself loaded, which is slightly different.  You can actually do it if you manage your own `dlopen()` / `dlclose()` calls instead of relying on `System.load()`.  Since everything is under the app's control, it's possible to do it safely.  That's really for a scenario where you want to update the shared library without restarting the app (or, more likely, service), whereas the question here is about overriding the system's copy of a library.

Comment: Hi all! Actually I wanted to unload a library that is loaded by default in Zygote so that I could load a different version of that library myself (in my DVM instance) and have the calls that would normally go to the original library go to mine instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Closing a shared library (with `dlclose()`) is tricky in the best of circumstances, because it will unmap the library's code.  If something later calls into that code -- perhaps a C++ destructor -- the program will immediately crash.  Since the library was loaded by code other than yours, it's entirely possible that another thread will be executing code in that library at the moment you unmap it, again causing a crash.

So, don't do that. :-)

If you can build your version of the library as a static lib and link it directly into your code, you should be able to avoid the problem entirely.

FWIW, various libraries (notably SSL and ICU) are linked into Dalvik, not explicitly loaded by the zygote, so if you're trying to replace one of those you'll get the `/system/lib` version whether you're forked from zygote or not.

Comment: Hi fadden!  Thanks!  I agree not to do that.  I pulled some other neat memory tricks to unmap it from memory directly, but I finally opted to use dlopen() to open it myself, then just pull out function pointers for what I needed using dlsym().  This is far more reliable.

Comment: Also, as a note about correctness - I would suggest fadden's answer involving using a static library if you are using a small library and/or just using it with one application.  I am building a suite of applications for a custom build of Android, thus statically linking it in 20 different things would be wasteful, so in that case, use my advice with dlopen()/dlsym()/dlclose()!

Comment: FWIW, your approach is why JNI has `UnregisterNatives` -- if any of the symbols you find with `dlsym()` are native method implementations, you can unregister them before calling `dlclose()`.

Comment: @fadden dont know if this will be on topic or not, but ICU has a `u_cleanup()` function that will cleanup all of its memory - assuming resources aren't in use by other threads (as you pointed out).